# c++ use #include only for part of code/ scoped #include/ stop #include

Tags: c++, scope, include

Suppose I would like to write a collection of static methods that look very similar, but do different tasks. Instead of writing to similar functions twice, it would be easier to write one and copy and paste the contents into the other.

The problem is that these methods use different header files for their functions. One such function pair might look like follows:

```
__global__  void D_sin(double* result, double x) {result[0]=sin(x);}
/*MACHINE*/ void H_sin(double* result, double x) {result[0]=sin(x);}
```

where the first one should use `#include "device_functions.h"`, and the second one should use `#include <cmath>`. Now `NVCC` for example might actually be smart enough to parse `__global__` and `__device__` functions properly, but I would still be interested in a general solution.

**I would like to keep these methods in the same file** because editing multiple files becomes very confusing very fast.

So the question is, how do I do something like this:

```
namespace a{
  #include "someheader.h"

  void a(double* a) {...;}
  void b(double* a, double x) {...;}
  void c(double* a, double x) {...;}
  void d(double* a, double* b, double x) {...;}

  #stopinclude "someheader.h"
}

namespace b{
  #include "anotherheader.h"

  void a(double* a) {...;}
  void b(double* a, double x) {...;}
  void c(double* a, double x) {...;}
  void d(double* a, double* b, double x) {...;}

  #stopinclude "anotherheader.h"
}
```

my original approach was

```
namespace someh {
   #include "someheader.h"
}
...
someh::...
{

  using namespace someh;
}
```

but I couldn't get consistent results with that.

Comment: Is it OK to divide the .cpp file into two files?

Comment: It's not clear what the real problem is. Sounds like a [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @RSahu is this better?

Comment: No, I still don't understand the core problem.

Comment: I'll think you'll be better off not tagging this with CUDA, in fact present it as a C++ only question (which it is).  Knowledgeable folks on the C++ tag may ignore it if they think it is CUDA related (which it isn't).  You want one section of a source file to be preprocessed with a certain set of compiler directives (`#include` statements) and another portion of the same file to be preprocessed with a different set of `#include` statements.  I don't know how to do that, and I don't think it really has anything to do with CUDA.  Certainly breaking it into 2 files is the obvious solution.